# Why does the code below highlight names at random?

Tags: javascript

I wrote this simple program to highlight some names in YouTube livechat:

```js
const friends = ["Bot Dude", "Flower Girl"];

function hl() {
    let authors = document.querySelectorAll("#author-name");

    for (let i = 0; i < authors.length; ++i)
        for (let j = 0; j < friends.length; ++j)
            if (authors[i].textContent === friends[j])
                authors[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}

setInterval(hl, 1500);
```

I simply paste this into the developer's console (of Google Chrome) and hit enter.

This code works; it'll highlight "Bot Dude" and "Flower Girl" without fail, but it also highlights other names at random! What's causing this behaviour? How can I fix this?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: Looking at your code, you appear to have multiple elements with `id="author-name"`. That's invalid HTML. Only a **single** element can have any given `id` value.

Comment: Please don't tag-spam. The question has nothing to do with [tag:google-chrome-devtools] or [tag:youtube] or, really, [tag:google-chrome] as opposed to any other browser.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's just how YouTube's livechat's HTML is.

Comment: Well *that's* unfortunate. :-| Good luck with it! :-)